# socket server client python - command line argument

Tags: python, server, command, client

I am new to Python and am working on a simple server client application for practice. I am trying to use the command line to pass arguments for the host and port and having some issues.

from socket import *

import sys
class client:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stderr.write("client is not implemented yet\n")



def connectTcp(host, port):

    try:
        a = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        host_address = gethostbyname(host)
        a.connect((host_address, port))
        a.close()
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

//driver code for testing

retval = client.connectTcp(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

if retval:
print("Connection established correctly")

else:
print("Some error")

//command line

python client.py [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) 80

//returns value

client is not implemented yet

Some error

//If I use this as my driver code

retval = client.connectTcp("www.google.com", 80)

if retval:

```
print("Connection established correctly")
```

else:

```
print("Some error")
```

//returns

client is not implemented yet

Connection established correctly

How can I properly pass the host and port through the command line as arguments instead of hard coding them in?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the raw command line arguments from sys.argv, or use a module like argparse for maximum flexibility.

Comment: Thats what I was trying to do in the first example of the driver code but when I plug sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2] for host and port, it returns "some error" meaning it did not connect properly.

Comment: Are you recasting your port number from a string to an integer? If you are, and hardcoded value with the same code works, I’d try printing what sys.argv[1|2] return (and their types) to make sure it’s getting what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Fail in connection doesn't mean the arguments are being wrongly passed. Personally, I tend to resort to the module `argpase`.

Nonetheless, in order to troubleshoot your solution, you could print the input arguments or use the module `pdb` to check the attribute values in memory. You could achieve this via the following code:

```py
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
retval = client.connectTcp(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

When in the `pdb` console, write `pp sys.argv[1]` and `pp sys.argv[2]`, this will allow you to check if your value is being correctly transmitted. To exit write `q`.